# Selecting an Image Slide on Slide Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've just been making my image slider and I've got it to animate left and right in an infinite loop and that works. What I'm having trouble doing now is selecting a image in the slides, on my jsFiddle example is a set of little boxes colored and it relates to their slide color when you select a slide at the top is should slide to the selected image but at this point it doesn't, would someone be able to help me accomplish this(selecting a slide at the top and sliding it to the left to the related color image) [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mdy5R/1/)

Im having problems with the index after you have selected a color the indexes should have a new starting index since the slide gets shifted to the end on the right but they don't seem to change if someone knows how to fix that then I could get somewhere.

jQuery:

```
$('.stages li a').on('click', function(e) {
    var slide = $('#' + $(this).data('slide'));
    $('.stages li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    goto_slide(slide);          
});


function goto_slide(slide) {
    var index = $(slide).index();

    var count = index;

    $('.slides ul').animate({'margin-left': '-=' + (item_width * (count - 1))}, 500, function() {
        $('.slides ul li').slice(0, count - 1).each(function() {
            $('.slides ul li:first').after($('.slides ul li:last'));                        
        })                  
    });

    $('#index').text(index);
}
```

I've updated my version and it's now working the way it should [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdy5R/2/).
I was able to get it working in the end, it is working pretty sweet now. The one improvement I would like todo is to get it to show only the next slide when you select the image slide at the top and hide the others that have an index in between the selected slide if you can do that for me it will look great give it ago if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is how you do it.

Step 1: Create a container div and set specific height and width for it. like below

```
<style>

.container{
    height:400px;
    width:500px;
    overflow:none;
    position : relative;
}

.container img{
    width : 400px;
    height : 500px;
    display:none;
    position : absolute;
    top : 0px;
}

.container img.selected{
    display : inline-block;
}

.container .nextslide{
    top : 0px;
    left : 500px;
}

</style>

<div class="container">
    <img ... class="selected"/>
    <img ... class=""/>
    <img ... class=""/>
    <img ... class=""/>
    ...
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
    var x=0;
    $(".container img").each(function(){
        $(this).css("left", x + "px"); x+=$(this).width();
    });

    window.setInterval(function(){
        var current = $("container img.selected");
        var next = current.next();
        next.addClass("nextslide);
        $(next).animate({ "left" : "0px"}, 500, function(){
            next.addClass("selected");
        });

        $(current).animate({ "left" : "-" + current.width() + "px"}, 500, function(){
            current.removeClass("selected");
        });
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

I think this should give you fairly good idea to create sliding images.

Comment: Thanks for sharing you're code. I was able to get it working in the end, it is working pretty sweet now. The one improvement I would like todo is to get it to show only the next slide when you select the image slide at the top and hide the others that have an index in between the selected slide if you can do that for me it will look great give it ago if you can.